# Looping through multiple files for multiple strings

Tags: linux, bash

Here's what I am trying to do:

```
file1val=cat data1 | awk '{print $5}'

file1nam=cat data1 | awk '{print $3}'

file2val=cat data2 | awk '{print $5}'

file3nam=cat data2 | awk '{print $3}'

if file1nam = file2name 

then do some code stuff for the file1val/file2val
```

else skip string then continue until all strings have been checked and echo results to a single file

Example:

data1 has the following strings

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 elmo red 13140667 Oct 13 22:20 65464654.tgz
-rw-r--r-- 1 oscar red 130667 Oct 13 22:20 6533464654.tgz
-rw-r--r-- 1 bert red 1313340667 Oct 13 22:20 654654.tgz
```

data2 has the following strings

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 elmo red 130667 Oct 11 22:20 6564654.tgz
-rw-r--r-- 1 bert red 13667 Oct 11 22:20 65464654.tgz
-rw-r--r-- 1 snuffy red 13123123140667 Oct 11 22:20 65464654.tgz
```

If elmo (filenam) exists in dat1 and data 2 then run this to compare its size:

```
perc=bc <<< "scale=2; ($file2val - $file1val)/$file1val * 100"
```

and output the results to a file:

```
elmo $perc

bert $perc
```

This needs to loop through each of the 20 or so line's that exists in data1 and data2 files.

Comment: Did you mean `file3nam` there? Because you don't have a `file2nam`.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: `elmo` is not filename, it's user name

Comment: Correct. elmo is not a filename. elmo is a user name that came from data1 or data2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I manage your divine your intentions correctly, you basically want to join the two files on the third field, and calculate a result from the respective values in the fifth field?

```
awk 'NR==FNR { v[$3] = $5; next }
    $3 in v { printf("%s %5.2f\n", $3, ($5-v[$3])/v[$3]*100) }' data1 data2
```

This is a fairly common Awk idiom; [google for `NR==FNR`](https://www.google.com/search?q=nr%3D%3Dfnr).